# Problema com JavaFX no Linux

Tags: linux, javafx

Alert do JavaFX no Linux.

Estou testando a tecnologia JavaFX, mas tenho notado algumas coisas que funcionam bem no windows mas não no Linux. Por exemplo, a classe javafx.scene.control.Alert, pra exibir janelas de alerta.
No Windows o alerta aparece perfeitamente. Já no Linux, ela aparece minúscula, com poucos pixels de largura/altura. E mesmo usando as funções setWidth e setHeight, não resolve.
Alguém já notou esse tipo de problema com JavaFX no Linux?

Comment: Você está usando o openjdk? Se sim, experimente usar o Oracle JDK.

Comment: Percebi que o problema é no Java 9. Na versão 8 do Java, os alerts aparecem perfeitamente.

Comment: Gustavo, é o da Oracle mesmo.